# Existence and uniqeness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with following task, reading book I have found following statment: "Solutions of Lotka-Volter model exists and are uniqe, because right side of equatation is polynominal". So I assume we want to use Picard theorem.
$$V'=V(a-b\cdot P)$$
$$P'=P(c\cdot V-d)$$
But how should I use it? I never had a chance to work with a system of differential equation. My main problem is to show it's Lipschitz continuity.  I mean for single differential: $x'=f(t,x)$ it's easy we have $||f(t,x)-f(t,y)||\le L\cdot ||x-y||$ Here we have two equations and I'm unsure how to write '$f$' function. My idea was: $$f(t,X)=(V(a-b\cdot P),P(c\cdot V-d))$$
where $X=(P,V)$ Is it correct? If not, I will be glad for plain explanation how to do it.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you define $f$ is correct. Now, to show that $f$ is (locally) Lipschitz, you use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: So just to be sure.Let's say we work on following interval [a,b] We know that $f$ is polynomial, so it'll obviously be continous and differenciable on it.  $$\frac{||f(t,X)-f(t,Y)||}{||X-Y||}\cdot ||X-Y||=\le f'(t,C) \cdot ||X-Y||=L \cdot ||X-Y||$$ using Mean Value Theorem such $C\in [a,b]$ exists

Comment: $X$ is a vector; you must use $\nabla f$ instead of $f'$.$$f(t,X)-f(t,Y)=\nabla f(t,\xi)\cdot(X-Y),$$where $\xi$ is a vector in the segment joining $X$ and $Y$. In your system $f$ does not depend on $t$, and since it is a polyniomial in $X$, $\nabla f$ is bounded on bounded sets.